# Angular form not available in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, asynchronous

I have a form in a controller which is loaded only when user presses a button inside a directive on which the event is relayed using $emit. But my problem is that the form is not available in the scope and thus the validation of the form is always invalid.
Here is my html,

```
<directive></directive>

<div class="col-md-12 editForm" ng-if="editMode">
    <form name="editPollForm" id="editPollForm" ng-submit="editPoll()" novalidate>
        <md-input-container>
             <inpu ng-model="payload.a" required>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
             <inpu ng-model="payload.b" required>
        </md-input-container>

         <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editPollForm.$invalid"> Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

controller function

```
$scope.$on('pollEditFormRequested', function(event){
    $scope.payload = {};
    $scope.payload.a = 'a';
    $scope.payload.b = 'b';

    $scope.editMode = true;
    console.log($scope.editPollForm);
});

$scope.editPoll = function(){
    console.log($scope.editPollForm);
    //call my submit edit form api

};
```

on $emit produced by directive is catched and values are populated, everything works fine but the submit button stays disabled as ediPollForm is outputting `undefined` on every `console.logs`

What am i doing wrong? I have tried `$timeout` and `$apply` but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the form is undefined is because ng-if creates a **new child scope**, hence the parent scope will have no clue about the new form.
In order to let it know you should wrap your form in a parent object.

```
$scope.form = {} //with this object the parent will hold a reference to the form 
//created in the child scope

$scope.$on('pollEditFormRequested', function(event){
    $scope.payload = {};
    $scope.payload.a = 'a';
    $scope.payload.b = 'b';

    $scope.editMode = true;
    console.log($scope.form.editPollForm); //here the form will be undefined 
    //because it's not created yet
});

$scope.editPoll = function(){
    console.log($scope.form.editPollForm);
    //call my submit edit form api

};
```

and in your template:

```
<div class="col-md-12 editForm" ng-if="editMode">
 <!--new scope here-->
    <form name="form.editPollForm" id="editPollForm" ng-submit="editPoll()" novalidate>
        <md-input-container>
             <inpu ng-model="payload.a" required>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
             <inpu ng-model="payload.b" required>
        </md-input-container>
         <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editPollForm.$invalid"> Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`